# Proper way of using past tense

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

which one is correct and why ?

1- I will help you once I understand how it works 
or
2- I will help you once I understood how it works

Comment: This question is better suited to our sister site, [ELL.SE]. At the moment we can not automatically migrate it there, but we can close it here so you can go re-ask it on that site.

Comment: Sorry for posting it here I will ask there

Comment: Yes, "I will help you once I understand how it works".

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53419/proper-way-of-using-past-tense, but I think the proper action is to merge the questions, not just closing it.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the past tense? You are using a future tense sentence, the understanding (and help) will come in the future. You first need a sentence that has past-tense meaning before asking about the proper usage. However, this is correct:

> I will help you once I understand how it works